# Force sharepoint to save files in directory

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'd like to force sharepoint to save files in directory. Is there a way to do that? 
I think about this scenario: users upload files to some list / library in sharepoint and automatically or by pushing "publish" the files are copied to some local server's directory.

Edit:
In other words i would like to connect sharepoint library with physical directory in server that runs IIS, so that files uploaded to library were seen in that folder.

I'm new to sharepoint.

Comment: Your question is unclear are you trying to upload files to a document library or to the local file system of the server running IIS (web front end)?  If the later this isn't supported or recommended in SharePoint and you should use the object model / Document Libraries to manipulate SharePoint.

Comment: SharePoint stores everything to Database.

Comment: We wrote a powershell script to extract all files from a Site Collection to a file system for a client. This is an ad-hoc request that comes along every now and then. It can be sceduled to run at any time and extract the files - the "why" is unimportant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you don't want to do this. If you're doing it in order to access the files from other applications, or having them show up in a users home directory or something, you can just map the document library as a network drive/web folder.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about [Remote BLOB Storage](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/sharepoint-2010-storing-documents-on-the-file-system-with-remote-blob-storage/)? I have not tried this and assume that RBS can be enabled for a Site level only and not for individual document libraries. If you want this for a particular doc library, you can write an event handler to save the uploaded documents to file system and then remove the uploaded file.

Comment: Well, I don't know. That might be helpful, but really there is no easier way? No way to publishing sharepoint content somewhere outside SharePoint itself?

Comment: I think the problem people are having is, why would you want to do this?  Maybe you can clarify that, so people can give you better answers.  In SP there are many ways to approach a problem and the correct approach depends on your intentions and reasons for doing what you are doing.

Comment: RBS would not provide for any type of access through the filing system to the files. RBS is specifically a mechanism for SharePoint storage only, not a way to extract files to the file system.

Comment: One of the main selling point of sharepoint is "Avoid multiple copies in filesystem and have it i one central place" and moving the files to filesystem breaks this. My solution has lot of issues too. After you delete the file from the library its gone forever from the library in sharepoint. There is no way to show the list of files in filesystem in the doc library. etc etc